# Could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: customization, acumatica

I just created new field on SOOrder screen and want to take the default value userRole of current user login into that textbox but it got error above. This is my coding:

```
 //Layout Editor: SO301000 (Sales Orders)
 [PXDBString(64)]
 [PXDefault(typeof(Coalesce<Search<UsersInRoles.userName,  Where<UsersInRoles.userName, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>, 
        Search<BAccount.ownerID, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>>>>), 
        PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
 [PXUIField(DisplayName="Current User" , Enabled = false)]

 error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'PX.Data.PXResultset' to 'PX.SM.UsersInRoles' in file: Code#SOOrderEntry(80)
 error: 'PX.Data.PXRowSelectingEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'NewValue' and no extension method 'NewValue' accepting a first argument of type 'PX.Data.PXRowSelectingEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in file: Code#SOOrderEntry(83)
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Users` and `UsersInRoles` DACs are located in `PX.SM` namespace.
You should either use `using PX.SM;` or specify namespace for these classes each time like `PX.SM.UsersInRoles.username`

P.S. Some letters have incorrect case in your example:

`UsersInRoles.userName` -> `UsersInRoles.username`

`Users.userName` -> `Users.username`

`Users.PKID` -> `Users.pKID`

Comment: I've already added **using PX.SM;** in Customize Business Logic but still got the same error.

Comment: Can you add a full file content to the question? It will be helpful. You can also try second way. Does it work?

Comment: On screen SOOrder I want to add new field that stores userRole of Current user login, but SOOrder only has ownerID so I need to join others like UsersInRole for taking username. I will edit my question above so please check it kindly.